# Why is then the mobility of holes lesser than the mobility of electrons?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

> In a semiconductor, mobility of holes is less than the mobility of the
>   electrons.

However, we know that, when an electron leaves its place, a hole is created. In other words, electron mobility constitutes hole current. Since moving electrons constitute hole current, why is then the mobility of holes lesser than the mobility of electrons?

Comment: No, electron mobility does not constitute hole current. Read up a bit, for example about doping, with holes or with electrons.

Answer (score 5):

The conduction electrons reside in the conduction band and the missing electrons (holes) reside in the valence band of the semiconductor. The conduction band electron effective mass is usually smaller than the valence band hole effective mass.This is one of the reasons that in a semiconductor the electron mobility is usually larger than the hole mobility.